# Select min value per item in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

Hello I have the following MySQL table:

```
id       item         value
1         A             11
2         A             20
3         B              2
4         C              1
5         B             14
6         C             12
```

What I'm trying to do is to select items with the lowest values - what I tried to do based on search of this forum is to use the following query:

```
  SELECT *,
         MIN(value) 
    FROM mytable 
GROUP BY item
```

The expected result should be **A => 11, B => 2; C => 1** however for some of the items the min value is correct and for some other items the min value is different value. Please note that mytable consist of approx ~100 rows.

Comment: What is the datatype of `value` ?

Comment: Do you need the `id` in the result?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL MIN/MAX returning proper value, but not the related record info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072710/mysql-min-max-returning-proper-value-but-not-the-related-record-info)

Comment: This question is asked several times every day on SO (and elsewhere). Quite often, it's correctly answered too. The topic is also covered thoroughly in the manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this way.

```
SELECT t.* FROM mytable  t
JOIN 
( SELECT item, MIN(value) minVal
  FROM mytable  GROUP BY item
) t2
ON t.value = t2.minVal AND t.item = t2.item;
```

Answer (score 1):

this would work in oracle

```
SELECT item, min(value)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY item
```

Comment: Ok, but when I added id to this; the id does not correspond to the id of the row with the lowest item + value... the value is INT but can be the same for multiple items. Can we improve this somehow to get the id of the lowest value with item visible?

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from mytable t1
inner join
(
  select min(value) value, id
  from mytable 
  group by id
) t2
  on t1.id = t2.id
  and t1.value= t2.value
```

Comment: It's unlikely that you would want to return all columns.

Answer (score 0):

If you need all information of min(value) for each item and datatype of "value" column is int, then run following query,

```
select * from mytable
where (item,value) in
(
   SELECT item, min(value)
   FROM mytable
   GROUP BY item
)
```

Please see [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cccc6/1)

Comment: Note that this uses a dependent subquery which means that performance is likely to be poor.