# MySQL Return Min and Max Value per Unique Item

Tags: mysql

I've got a table called scheduleData which contains the following columns:

```
ID | CREATED (time stamp) | CLIENT | PROJECT | RESOURCE | EFFORT | WEEK (date)
```

The data comes straight from an "Excel schedule", hence it's not relational. 
Each row represents a resource that's booked on a particular project in a particular week.

Each time the data is exported from excel much of the data is duplicated, so i'm only ever interested in the latest data set based on the CREATED column.

For each project I want to return a row showing the MIN and MAX week, within the latest data set (based on CREATED) to essentially determine the start and end date for each project.

Found a the example below which from the description seems to do the trick but I get error message when i try to execute it

```
SELECT t.* FROM scheduleData  t
JOIN 
( SELECT project, MIN(week) minVal
FROM scheduleData  GROUP BY project
) t2
ON t.week = t2.minVal AND t.project = t2.project;
```

Adapted the following example: [Select min value per item in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32068307/select-min-value-per-item-in-mysql)

Cheers,
Mikael

Comment: You need to add "AS" to MIN(week) minVal so that it reads "MIN(week) AS minVal"

Comment: Something is missing from this question. What do you think that might be? Also, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

realized when I looked at this with fresh eyes that I was just being a bit thick, and that my question was a bit rubbish. Anyway, I've managed to adapt the query to do exactly what I want, i.e. return the max and minimum value (in this instance a date) for any given unique item, in this case a project. 
The SQL for this is as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(t.week), t.project, t.client 
FROM scheduleData  t
JOIN 
( SELECT project, MIN(week) AS minVal, MAX(week) as maxVal 
FROM scheduleData  GROUP BY project) t2
ON ( t.date = t2.minVal OR t.date = t2.maxVal) AND t.project = t2.project
```